# Supabase: Query all rows in which either of two child relations contains property

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

Let's say I own a bunch of malls that have stores and restaurants. **I want to query for all malls in which at least 1 store OR at least 1 restaurants is open**

There are three tables, malls, stores and restaurants.

**malls**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| mall 1 | Josh's Mall |
| mall 2 | Sarah's Mall |

**stores**

| id | name | isOpen | mallId (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Express | false | mall 1 |
| 2 | Banana Republic | false | mall 2 |

**restaurants**

| id | name | isOpen | mallId (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PF Changs | true | mall 1 |
| 2 | Panda Express | false | mall 2 |

Each individual store and restaurant is its own row within its respective table. Every store and restaurant contains a foreign key relation to the malls table that says that it belongs to that mall.

**I want to query for all malls in which at least 1 store OR at least 1 restaurant is in stock. Since malls only have stores and restaurants, I'm basically querying malls that have something open**

*in this case the expected result would be Josh's mall since PF Changs is open*

I've been working with this but it seems that you need to specify the foreign table for a .or() request.

```
      .from("malls")
      .select("name, store!inner( isOpen ), restaurants!inner( isOpen )")
      .or("store.isOpen.eq.true, restaurants.isOpen.eq.true")
```

When I want to specify the foreign table separately, how do I include both?

```
      .from("malls")
      .select("name, stores!inner( isOpen ), restaurants!inner( isOpen )")
      .or('isOpen.eq.true', { foreignTable: "stores" }) //but then where would i specify the restaurants table?
```

In psudo code, i want to do this

```
      .from("malls")
      .select("name, stores!inner( isOpen ), restaurants!inner( isOpen )")
     .or(
          .filter("stores.isOpen", "eq", true)
          .filter("restaurants.isOpen", "eq", true)
        )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello! I hope it's not too late, but I have a similar problem, did you manage to solve it? And how did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like stores and restaurants are really the same thing with maybe slightly different attributes. Would it make sense to put them inside a same table like this?

**venues**

| id | name | isOpen | mallId (foreign key) | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Express | false | mall 1 | store |
| 2 | Banana Republic | false | mall 2 | store |
| 3 | Panda express | false | mall 2 | restaurant |

For the type, you can use enums in Postgres.

```sql
create type venu_type as enum ('store', 'restaurant');
```

This way you can easily query malls that have at least 1 venue open.

If you absolutely must separate the store and restaurants in different tables, you can create a view that combines the two to and perform or on the view. You can create a view like this:

```sql
create or replace view venues
as
    select
       id
       name
       is_open
       mall_id
    from restaurants
    union all
    select
       id
       name
       is_open
       mall_id
    from stores;
```

Once a view is created, you can query against the view just like you would query against a table using Supabase.

Comment: for organizational purposes, i'd prefer to keep them in separate tables. I'm not sure where to go from here. I was thinking to union open resurants and open stores in the sql query? what are your thoughts on that

Comment: @KishanSripada If you really want to separate the tables, then you can create a view that combines the two. I will edit my answer right now to show you how you can do that.

Comment: will the view update to reflect changing data in both tables?

Comment: @KishanSripada Yup, the view will dynamically update in real time as either one of the table updates!